# md-input-container issue on k-rebind

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-material

I'm facing troubles when using md-input-container directive with the k-rebind event of Kendo UI. The issue ocurrs when I tried to rebind the min value for the end date (Second datepicker).

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.8.1/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <input id="datepicker" kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="date" />
    <md-input-container>
      <label>End Date</label>
      <input id="datepicker" kendo-date-picker k-min="date" k-rebind="date" />
    </md-input-container>
  </div>

<script>
  angular
   .module('app', ['kendo.directives', 'ngMaterial'])
   .controller('appController', function (){});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue ocurrs because when Kendo performs the rebinding, it clones the input node; but I am not sure of that.

Have you ever faced this issue? Or How do you get working both (md-input-container and k-rebind) together?